# How to achieve low latency for live audio: new soundcard or computer?

Tags: daw, studio

I currently run studio one pro 5 on a XPS 15 with maxed out settings. I want to use it for live audio performance and I am getting some audio glitches when using 64 buffer size. I am using a RME Babyface that is a couple years old.

I am now wondering what affects the smallest buffer size you can use: is it my processor or my audio card?

Comment: Why do you want a smaller buffer than 64? As I understand it you play a sampler in your computer. Sound is then output from the computer (nothing coming in). A buffer size of 64 is slightly less than 2 milliseconds and should not be perceptible. What am i missing here?

Comment: I am processing a guitar input as well as my voice and at around 128 I start noticing some delay, especially in the voice part. This is very annoying and hard to overcome. I have found that I can just directly monitor my voice from the Babyface but thats not giving me the whole picture of whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest buffer you can use is the next one up from the one that glitches.
The computer itself is the main cause of buffer under-run. The external hardware is probably non-adjustable.
The more processing you're running live, the larger the buffers will need to be. Try to get all processing pre-rendered if you're using playback tracks, don't try to run a whole live mix with 92 tracks & all the plugins running, use a stereo 'finished product', so all you're running live is your guitar amp etc.

Back in the days of WinXP, people used to hone down a system until the only things running were those involved in the audio framework. Modern OSes you can't really do that, but the hardware is 50 times faster. If you really want to try slim it down, you'll probably end up with a computer you can't use for anything else.

Do make sure you're using ASIO or similar, not Windows' own sound drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying a sample size of 48 samples instead of 64.  At 48000Hz sample rate, this makes for a sampling interval of 1ms which may map better to the timer resolution of the computer (and the USB protocol) than 4/3ms does.